# How to automatically bring an activated window to the foreground?

Tags: 14.04, unity, window, filemanager, focus

When I have a file browser and an image viewer opened and I double click a photo, the image viewer doesn't jump to the foreground, its icon just shakes a bit and acquires a glow around it, and I have to manually click on it to actually see the photo. How could I make it automatic, so that a double click on a photo shows it immediately, even when the image viewer is already opened in the background?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This behaviour can be changed from the command line, open a terminal and type:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 0
```

To restore the default value:

```
dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/focus-prevention-level 1
```

Comment: hi, strange, in my ubuntu 14.04 there is no setting "focus-prevention-level" at this place :-| , any ideas ?

Comment: @user157697, you should be able to find the setting via CCSM. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/514462/301745).

Comment: Thank you so much for this. The default behavior was wildly irritating to me.

Comment: Worked for me on 14.04