# Open containing folder instantly

Tags: unity, 15.04, launcher, filemanager

i have problem with open containing folder in ff/chromium instead instant open it open it minimized into launcher ( So the file explorer icon shake )  How can i force to open it instantly without minimizing it ? 
Thank you for all help :)

Comment: What you mean is probably *not raised* instead of *minimized*.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/a/594301/72216

Comment: Glad it works :)