# How can I prevent an application window from opening in background?

Tags: unity, 15.10, rhythmbox, window, minimize

On my Ubuntu 15.10 Rhythmbox frequently, but not always, opens its main window in the background when launching it through the Unity launcher icon (see below).

How can I force this application to always open its main window in the foreground?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked its preferences ?

Comment: Yes, there is no respective setting in the preferences.

Comment: Waitwait, in the background, meaning not in front, or minimized? My answer possibly misses its target. In the first case, another answer is appropriate.

Comment: @JacobVlijm by "in the background" I refer to the window opening not in front.

Comment: Waitwait, the link *does* work, could you try? Yep, it does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically bring an activated window to the foreground?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594294/how-to-automatically-bring-an-activated-window-to-the-foreground)