# How do I automatically raise a window, called by a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: 14.04

So I've read through the tutorials on how to setup the web browser keyboard shortcuts but I can't seem to find how to make the default web browser keyboard shortcut appear on top.

I'm going to settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> launcher -> launch web browser.

I've set it to <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Whenever I execute the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> command it launches a new web browswer....but in the background. How can I have it launch in the foreground?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to automatically bring an activated window to the foreground?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594294/how-to-automatically-bring-an-activated-window-to-the-foreground)

Comment: No. I want to be able to hit Shift + Ctrl + I from anywhere and have a fresh internet browser appear in the foreground. That is not a keyboard shortcut

Comment: You don't understand, the linked answer makes new windows raise to the fron, which is your issue.

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand and it worked

Comment: Cool :) Glad it works. You can close it as a dupe yourself, as "Community". The linked answer will then be findable through your question.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it on my laptop. You should create a custom shortcut with the command:

> exo-open --launch WebBrowser

It starts on the foreground for me.

Source: xubuntu