# Is there a way to automatically show a window opened by another program?

Tags: unity, nautilus, firefox

I came from a Windows background and just started using Ubuntu about two weeks ago.

I noticed something weird about the Unity window manager that just makes it feel quite unnatural:

For example, When I download a file in Firefox and click the button to open the folder in nautilus, it always opens minimized. I have to manually go to the launcher and click on the icon to see the window. The same thing happens when any program is started by another program.

I would expect to see the nautilus / any other window show up but instead just get into a state of confusion for a while until I realize that it's actually opened, but it's minimized.

Is there a way to allow windows opened by another program to not be minimized by default?

Comment: Check this thread out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/514450/programs-never-open-in-foreground , might answer your question.

Comment: seems like exact duplicate of that question. Let us know if the answer in that post helped you

Comment: Yes it was a duplicate of that question, and it did solve the issue. Thanks